# how can i write it You username has been updated or Your username has been updated

Tags: grammar, errors

Which is correct?

You username has been updated or Your username has been updated

or something else i am not sure i dont speak very well english so making sure i am writing right

Answer (score -1, accepted):

YOUR USERNAME. You- is of a singular address. From one to another. YOUR- is of singular address but with the inclusion of something you own, control, have. BELONGING to you. Not to be confused with you're . Which is a shortening of you are.